# Value is not updating when sending to Access

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, export

My values for `AmeriFood(i), SpanFood(i), IndiFood(i)` are not updating when it exports to my Access table.  Instead it continuously inputs the first instance of the value every time throughout the loop.

```
    InsertIntoString = "INSERT INTO [Data] ([American], [Spanish], [Indian]) "
''''ValuesString = "VALUES ([" & AmerFood(i) & "], [" & SpanFood(i) & "], [" & IndiFood(i) & "])"  ' I couldnt get this to work beauce there are spaces in the string.
ValuesString = "VALUES (?,?,?)"
strSql = InsertIntoString & ValuesString

With cmd
    Set .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = strSql
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVariant, adParamInput, , AmerFood(i))
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVariant, adParamInput, , SpanFood(i))
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVariant, adParamInput, , IndiFood(i))
    .Execute
End With
```

Any idea how to make the values `AmeriFood(i), SpanFood(i), IndiFood(i)` update each time it loops in the VBA code?  Ive stepped through the code and each value does update with the correct text/value, but it never exports as that updated value, just the first value it was given.

I was origonally going to use the commented out line

```
ValuesString = "VALUES ([" & AmerFood(i) & "], [" & SpanFood(i) & "], [" & IndiFood(i) & "])"
```

but it was erroring out because there are spaces in the variable strings.

it doesn't make a difference to me which way I do this, I just need something working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to share the full code, but as far as I can see, you're repeatedly adding parameters to the same command.

Use a new command for each iteration:

```
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    Set .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = strSql
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVariant, adParamInput, , AmerFood(i))
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVariant, adParamInput, , SpanFood(i))
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVariant, adParamInput, , IndiFood(i))
    .Execute
End With
```

Note that `adVariant` is unsupported, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/datatypeenum)